# CMake build can't find Qt6 library in /usr/local

Tags: ubuntu, qt, cmake, arm64, ldconfig

I have an Orange Pi 5, an arm64 SBC running *Joshua Riek's Ubuntu 22.04.4 for RK3588* ([link to project](https://github.com/Joshua-Riek/ubuntu-rockchip)).

I'm trying to build [Duckstation](https://github.com/stenzek/duckstation), a PS1 emulator, which depends on Qt 6.6.2. The latest arm64 Qt version I have available through apt is version 6.2.4.

I'm building Qt 6.6.2 from source, but I'm having issues linking the built library to the Duckstation cmake build.

#### Building Qt 6.6.2 from git

The Qt installer application is not available for arm64, so I followed Qt's documentation on how to build Qt6 from git, found [here](https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_6_from_Git). The steps I have taken are as follows:

1. Clone the Qt6 repository and switch to 6.6.2 branch

```
$ git clone git://code.qt.io/qt/qt5.git qt6
$ cd qt6
$ git switch 6.6.2
```

2. Initialize the submodules with init-repository script

```
$ perl init-repository
```

3. Create a build directory and configure

```
$ mkdir build && cd build
$ ../configure
```

I left the -prefix attribute out, by default it will be set to `/usr/local/Qt-6.6.2`

4. Build the whole Qt6 library and install

```
$ cmake --build . --parallel $(nproc)
$ sudo cmake --install .
```

Building the full library takes over an hour on this platform. After installing, the contents of the directory `/usr/local/Qt-6.6.2` look like this:

[image]

#### Building Duckstation

Following the build instructions on Duckstation's readme, here are the build steps

1. Clone the repository

```
$ git clone https://github.com/stenzek/duckstation.git duckstation
$ cd duckstation
```

2. Create a build directory and configure

```
$ mkdir build
$ cmake -Bbuild -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

When trying to configure the build, I'm getting an error locating the Qt 6.6.2:

[image]

**How do I link the built library to the CMake build?**

I have tried creating an ldconfig file `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/Qt-6.6.2.conf` which contains

```
/usr/local/Qt-6.6.2/bin
/usr/local/Qt-6.6.2/lib
```

After creating the file, I ran `sudo ldconfig`.

If it's not a linking issue, am I installing the Qt6 to a wrong location, or missing some critical configuration step in the build?

As a sidenote: I'm able to build Duckstation successfully by patching the required Qt version to 6.2.4 and by modifying the sources a bit, but I'd like to be able to build the main branches, for handling updates more easily etc.

Comment: Although the Linux build instructions appear to assume that Qt6 will be in a standard location, if you scroll down to the [macOS](https://github.com/stenzek/duckstation?tab=readme-ov-file#macos-1) section it mentions a `-DQt6_DIR` cmake flag that may be helpful in this situation?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please don't post [screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). They are often difficult to read, the content will not show up in search engine results, and contributors trying to help will have to type-copy content when trying to analyze/reproduce your problem. Instead, paste it into the question using code formatting.

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you, that did the trick. I'll post an answer to resolve this question

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @steeldriver for pointing out the -DQt6_DIR cmake flag.

I added the flag to the command, so it finally looked like this:

```
$ cmake -Bbuild -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DQt6_DIR:PATH=/usr/local/Qt-6.6.2/lib/cmake/Qt6
```

The build files were now generated successfully and I was also able to compile the project.

When wondering how to list such directory related flags, I learned about `cmake -LAH` from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42945360). When running it at the Duckstation project's root, the Qt6_DIR entry looked like this:

```
Qt6_DIR:PATH=Qt6_DIR-NOTFOUND
```

In the future I'm hopefully able to solve build configuration issues more easily using that command.